# Запоминать cookie при клике

Tags: cookie

Прошу помощи в доработки скрипта.

Есть скрипт для сайта с алкоголем. При первом заходе на этот сайт всплывает окно. Если в этом окне нажать ***"Нет"***, то идёт переход в гугл. Если вернуться на страницу *"18+"* снова, то страница показывается уже без всплывающего окна.

Чуть ниже второй код, который я пытался доработать, но всплывающее окно показывается при каждом обновлении страницы, в независимости от ответа пользователя.  (вариант работающего скрипта взят отсюда kvz1926.ru/js/scripts.js)

```
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        // Проверим, есть ли запись в куках о посещении посетителя
        // Если запись есть - ничего не делаем
        if (!$.cookie('was')) {
            // Покажем всплывающее окно
            $('#boxUserFirstInfo').arcticmodal({
                    closeOnOverlayClick: false,
                    closeOnEsc: true
            });
        }

        // Запомним в куках, что посетитель к нам уже заходил
        $.cookie('was', true, {
                expires: 365,
                path: '/'
        });
    })
})(jQuery)
```

Пример доработанного кода (`.yes-click` - ответ, что есть *18*, а `.no-click`, что нет *18*)

**Вопрос такой: Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии .yes-click куки запоминались?**

```
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        // Проверим, есть ли запись в куках о посещении посетителя
        // Если запись есть - ничего не делаем
        if (!$.cookie('was')) {
            // Покажем всплывающее окно
            $('#boxUserFirstInfo').arcticmodal({
                closeOnOverlayClick: false,
                closeOnEsc: true
            });
        }

        $('.no-click').click(function() {
            window.location.href = 'http://www.google.ru/';
            return false
        });

        $('.yes-click').click(function() {
            $.cookie(cookie, 'was', {
                expires: 365,
                path: '/'
            });
            return false
        })
    })
})(jQuery)
```

Comment: `$.cookie(cookie, 'was', {` первый параметр точно нужен?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman изучаю вот js, не до конца вник в синтаксис =( делаю по примерам

Comment: а почему при копировании примера код вдруг поменялся?

Answer (score 1):

Замените на вот такой код

```
$('.yes-click').click(function() {
    $.cookie('was', true, {
        expires: 365,
        path: '/'
    });
    return false
})
```

Comment: то что нужно, но можете пояснить почему первый пример использует вырезанную часть кода

Comment: какой именно пример? и про какую часть кода вы спрашиваете?

Comment: первый код в моём вопросе =)

Comment: а что такое вырезанная часть кода? первый пример, просто проверяет есть ли у пользователя cookie или нет. если нет, то показывает окно и устанавливает cookie. если cookie есть, то просто обновляет дату окончания хранения cookie.

Answer (score 1):

Писал подобный скрипт, но на localStorage, вот, если нужно

P.s. Тут работать не будет, только "у себя".

```js
// Лучше добавить в <head>
$(document).ready(function(){
  if(localStorage.getItem('ConfirmationOfAge')=='1') 
  $('#COA').remove();
});

$('#COA').find('.COA-button button').on('click',function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('COA-button--yes')){
    localStorage.setItem('ConfirmationOfAge','1');
    $('#COA').remove();
  }
  if($(this).hasClass('COA-button--no'))
    location.href = 'http://www.google.com/';
});
```

```css
#COA {
  z-index: 9999;
  color: #fff;
}
#COA,
#COA .COA-overlay {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

#COA .COA-overlay {
  background: #bdc3c7;
}
#COA .COA-form {
  display: block;
  width: 600px;
  height: 135px;
  background: #2b2b2b;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
#COA .COA-form .COA-mess {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
#COA .COA-form .COA-button {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
#COA .COA-form .COA-button button {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#COA .COA-form .COA-button button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px #fff;
}
#COA .COA-form .COA-button button.COA-button--yes {
  background-color: #2ecc71;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
#COA .COA-form .COA-button button.COA-button--no {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- в конец <body> -->

<div id="COA">
<div class="COA-overlay"></div>
<div class="COA-form">
<div class="COA-mess">
Данный сайт может содержать контент, предназначенный для лиц старше 18 лет.<br>
Чтобы продолжить, подтвердите возраст.<br><br>
Вам уже есть 18?
</div>
<div class="COA-button">
<button class="COA-button--yes">Да</button>
<button class="COA-button--no">Нет</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```